# Why pixelPos = (y*canvasWidth + x) * 4?

Tags: javascript

Why, in Javascript, do we do `pixelPos = (y*canvasWidth + x) * 4` in order to get the pixel position in a canvas? I don't understand why we multiply y and x by the canvasWidth and by 4.

For example:

```
function getColorIndicesForCoord(x, y, width) {
  var red = y * (width * 4) + x * 4;
  return [red, red + 1, red + 2, red + 3];
}
```

Also is the function above is similar to doing this:

```
var red = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
var data = red.data;
var pixel_color = [data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]];
```

Thank you

Comment: Fun-fact: many 2D drawing systems (like Windows' GDI) [also align each horizontal row of pixels to a machine's native word-size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride), so rather than multiplying by the canvas width, you multiply by the raster stride size (which would be something like `width + ( width % sizeof(void*))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply by 4 because each pixel occupies 4 bytes in the format you're using.

Multiply y by the width because each row comes after the previous row — to move down one row you skip one row's worth (`width`) of pixels. To get to the `y`th row you skip `y*width`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So essentially, the entire canvas is like a 2d array and in order to get a pixel position we would do (y*canvasWidth + x) * 4. You also said each pixel occupies 4 bytes in the format I'm using. Is there another format available for me to use? I'm new to JavaScript. Many thanks

Comment: @DavidAlas maybe. I have no idea what you are using, since the question didn't say, but in the wide world in general there are lots of different pixel formats.

Comment: They are using an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData), and it stores pixels data as [R,G,B,A,R,G...

Comment: @DavidAlas If you use a `TypedArray` using a 32-bit element type (such as `Uint32Array` or `Int32Array`) then each `x,y` array index would map to a single pixel on-screen which is basically what you're asking, but you'd then need to bit-shift each retrieved value to get the RGBA channel pixel data (assuming 8 bits per channel). The advantage of working at the byte-level is that you can directly access each color-channel of each pixel in a single step.